# MySQL Multiple IF statements within after insert trigger fails

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have been working on this for about 2 days and am at my wits end. SOS StackExchange Gurus! Can anybody help me PLEASE?!

Okay, so I've got the following two triggers set up - one works the other doesn't. They are almost identical but for the latter containing two IF statements the other containing only one. Can anyone help remove the 2014 error I keep getting?

This trigger WORKS:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS AFTER_INSERT_wp_bp_xprofile_data;
CREATE TRIGGER `AFTER_INSERT_wp_bp_xprofile_data` 
AFTER INSERT ON wp_bp_xprofile_data 
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

DECLARE cou_id, voc_id tinyint(3);
DECLARE cou_change, voc_change int(100);

    SELECT COUNT(*) 
        INTO cou_change FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data a 
        JOIN dim_country b 
        ON b.bp_xprofile_fields_parent_id = a.field_id 
        WHERE b.bp_xprofile_fields_parent_id =NEW.field_id;

    SELECT COUNT(*) 
        INTO voc_change FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data c
        JOIN dim_vocation d
        ON d.bp_xprofile_fields_parent_id = c.field_id 
        WHERE c.bp_xprofile_fields_parent_id =NEW.field_id;

    IF 

/*COUNTRY*/
        cou_change > 0

    THEN 
        SELECT country_id
        INTO cou_id
        FROM dim_country x
        JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_fields y
            on x.bp_xprofile_fields_id = y.id
        JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data w
            on w.field_id = y.parent_id
        WHERE y.name=NEW.value 
            and w.id=NEW.id;  

     UPDATE fact_user_profile_detail z
        SET z.country_id = cou_id
        WHERE z.user_id = NEW.user_id;

     END IF;
END; $$

DELIMITER ;
```

This trigger DOES NOT :

```
DELIMITER $$ 

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS AFTER_INSERT_wp_bp_xprofile_data;
CREATE TRIGGER AFTER_INSERT_wp_bp_xprofile_data 
AFTER INSERT ON wp_bp_xprofile_data
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

DECLARE cou_id, voc_id tinyint(3);
DECLARE cou_change, voc_change int(100);

    SELECT COUNT(*) 
        INTO cou_change FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data a 
        JOIN dim_country b 
        ON b.bp_xprofile_fields_parent_id = a.field_id 
        WHERE b.bp_xprofile_fields_parent_id =NEW.field_id;

    SELECT COUNT(*) 
        INTO voc_change FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data c
        JOIN dim_vocation d
        ON d.bp_xprofile_fields_parent_id = c.field_id 
        WHERE c.bp_xprofile_fields_parent_id =NEW.field_id;

    IF 

/*COUNTRY*/
        cou_change > 0

    THEN 
        SELECT country_id
        INTO cou_id
        FROM dim_country x
        JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_fields y
            on x.bp_xprofile_fields_id = y.id
        JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data w
            on w.field_id = y.parent_id
        WHERE y.name=NEW.value 
            and w.id=NEW.id;  

     UPDATE fact_user_profile_detail z
        set z.country_id = cou_id
        WHERE z.user_id = NEW.user_id;

     ELSE IF

  /*VOCATION*/   
       voc_change > 0

      then
           SELECT vocation_id
            INTO voc_id
            FROM dim_vocation xx
            JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_fields yy
                on xx.bp_xprofile_fields_id = yy.id
            JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data ww
                on ww.field_id = yy.parent_id
            WHERE yy.name = NEW.value 
                and ww.id = NEW.id; 

           UPDATE fact_user_profile_detail zz
            set zz.vocation_id = voc_id
            WHERE zz.user_id = NEW.user_id;


     END IF;
END; 
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I found the problem ```ELSE IF``` should have been ```ELSEIF```~

Comment: Use `CASE WHEN (select1)>0 THEN update1 WHEN (select2)>0 THEN update2 END CASE`.